# Angular 5 --prod fails in browser, --aot does not

Tags: angular, angular-cli, firebase-hosting

I am developing a web app using Angular 5. Using `ng serve` it renders in my localhost:4200 perfectly. When I run `ng serve --prod` my browser loads nothing and throws this error:

```
    ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'OVERWRITE' of undefined
    at new e (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1149086)
    at e.applyServerOverwrite (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:129317)
    at e.updateInfo_ (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1171422)
    at new e (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1169637)
    at e.createRepo (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1533)
    at e.databaseFromApp (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:975)
    at Object.t.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference [as database] (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1209912)
    at e._getService (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:641580)
    at e.s.(anonymous function) [as database] (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:643503)
    at new e (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:664222)
Oe @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.handleError @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.run @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.runOutsideAngular @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onInvoke @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.run @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onInvokeTask @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.runTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
v @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
Promise resolved (async)
d @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
P @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.then @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.appInitializer @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.runInitializers @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onInvoke @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.run @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.run @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.bootstrapModuleFactory @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
cDNt @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
o @ inline.e029292f71a17d803f23.bundle.js:1
0 @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
o @ inline.e029292f71a17d803f23.bundle.js:1
window.webpackJsonp @ inline.e029292f71a17d803f23.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'OVERWRITE' of undefined
    at new e (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1149086)
    at e.applyServerOverwrite (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:129317)
    at e.updateInfo_ (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1171422)
    at new e (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1169637)
    at e.createRepo (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1533)
    at e.databaseFromApp (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:975)
    at Object.t.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference [as database] (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1209912)
    at e._getService (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:641580)
    at e.s.(anonymous function) [as database] (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:643503)
    at new e (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:664222)
main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'OVERWRITE' of undefined
    at new e (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.applyServerOverwrite (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.updateInfo_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
    at main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
    at Object.t.forEach (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.F1yO.t.each (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.onServerInfoUpdate_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at t.handleTimestamp_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at t.onReady_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
Oe @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.handleError @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
next @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.object.i @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.__tryOrUnsub @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.next @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t._next @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.next @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.next @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.emit @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.run @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.runOutsideAngular @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
onHandleError @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.handleError @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.runTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
_ @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
k @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'OVERWRITE' of undefined
    at new e (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.applyServerOverwrite (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.updateInfo_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.onConnectStatus_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at t.onRealtimeDisconnect_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.close (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1)
Oe @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.handleError @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
next @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.object.i @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.__tryOrUnsub @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.next @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t._next @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.next @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.next @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.emit @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.run @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.runOutsideAngular @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
onHandleError @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.handleError @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.runTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
n.args.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
setTimeout (async)
c @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
d @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
i.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
F1yO.t.setTimeoutNonBlocking @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.start_ @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
i.g @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
Ze @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
Ye @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
TL6u.e.Qb @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
ke @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onInvoke @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.run @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onInvokeTask @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.runTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
v @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
n.args.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
setTimeout (async)
c @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
d @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
i.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleConnect_ @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.onOnline_ @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.on @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.createRepo @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.databaseFromApp @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e._getService @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
s.(anonymous function) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
se @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
xi @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
Ii @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
xi @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
Ii @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.get @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
po @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
co @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
so @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
Uo @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
Lo @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
na @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.create @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t.create @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.bootstrap @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e._moduleDoBootstrap @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onInvoke @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.run @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onInvokeTask @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.runTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
v @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
Promise resolved (async)
d @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
P @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.then @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.appInitializer @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.runInitializers @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
onInvoke @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.run @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.run @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.bootstrapModuleFactory @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
cDNt @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
o @ inline.e029292f71a17d803f23.bundle.js:1
0 @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
o @ inline.e029292f71a17d803f23.bundle.js:1
window.webpackJsonp @ inline.e029292f71a17d803f23.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1 FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined
    at http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1186752
    at e.newRequest_ (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1186856)
    at e.startLongPoll (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1186493)
    at e.start (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1182574)
    at e.onHandshake_ (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1077185)
    at e.onControl_ (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1076527)
    at e.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1076067)
    at e.onMessage_ (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1074274)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:1063122
    at Object.F1yO.t.exceptionGuard (http://localhost:4200/main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1:120625) 
F1yO.t.warn @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.runTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
invoke @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
n.args.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
setTimeout (async)
c @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
d @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
i.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1
F1yO.t.exceptionGuard @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
t @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
i @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
e.handleResponse @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
pRTLPCB @ .lp?start=t&ser=53021794&cb=1&v=5&ns=strongholdings-40ee8:6
(anonymous) @ .lp?start=t&ser=53021794&cb=1&v=5&ns=strongholdings-40ee8:9
polyfills.a77f1d02ca80765f17f1.bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined
    at main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
    at e.newRequest_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.startLongPoll (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.start (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.onHandshake_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.onControl_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at e.onMessage_ (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
    at main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1
    at Object.F1yO.t.exceptionGuard (main.03f1154228018f30c0ac.bundle.js:1)
```

Using `ng serve --aot` the project again renders perfectly. I wanted to deploy so I did a `ng build --aot` and that deployed to firebase correctly and it works. Why am I getting this error with the `ng serve --prod` and is it safe to continue to deploy `--aot` builds? Also Angular CLI does not throw errors when I do a `ng build --prod`

Any help?

Comment: It is safe, but you'll lose Performance. However we can't really help you without the actual code.

Comment: where does this object `OVERWRITE` points to. Can you please add the relevant code

Comment: that's where I am confused, I never used this object `OVERWRITE`. I am assuming it is being injected somewhere during production builds

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you using an old version of acorn (or one of your dependancy is using it) ?
https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/issues/608

Can you try updating to ^5.2.1

Comment: webpack is currently using `"acorn": "5.3.0",
        "acorn-dynamic-import": "2.0.2",`

Answer (score 0):

Some where in project, you are using a **depreciated**  method `firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken` . Replace getToken with **getIdToken(true)**

Example :

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```